# List all the upper and lowercase letters in a string

Tags: python

I want to list all the upper and lowercase letters in a string,but the code below in python isn't working:

```
def up_low(s):
    for letter in s :
        v = []
        v1 = []
        if letter.islower() :
            v = v.append(1)
        elif letter.isupper():
            v1=v1.append(1)
        else :
            pass
        return len(v)
        return len(v1)

print(up_low("Hello Siam,'How are You Today?'"))
```

Comment: You keep setting `v` and `v1` to an empty list `[]` within the loop. You must initialize them _before_ the `for` line. You also return the `len(v)` and the function terminates as you can only return once. Next time please clarify "what is not working" and "what is your expected output".

Comment: If you want to return two things return a `tuple` like `return len(v), len(v1)`

Answer (score 1):

Your current code fails because you keep resetting `v` and `v1` to an empty list every time you pick a new letter.  You can do this more directly with list comprehensions:

```
v  = [char for char in s if char.islower()]
v1 = [char for char in s if char.isupper()]
```

However, since what you *really* want is the count, simply add the Boolean values (which are True = 1 and False = 0)

```
len_lower = sum(char.islower() for char in s)
len_upper = sum(char.isupper() for char in s)
```

... and there are your two values to return

Answer (score 1):

```py
def up_low(s):
    v = []
    v1 = []
    for letter in s :
        #v = []
        #v1 = []
        if letter.islower() :
            #v = v.append(1) # this is wrong, you are reinitializing everytime
            v.append(1)
        elif letter.isupper():
            #v1=v1.append(1) # this is wrong, you are reinitializing everytime
            v1.append(1)
        else :
            pass
    return (len(v), len(v1))
        #return len(v1) you can't have 2 return statements in a single function in same scope

print(up_low("Hello Siam,'How are You Today?'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion, regex can also easily handle your requirement:

```py
def up_low(s):
    print('lower: ' + re.sub(r'[^a-z]+', '', s))
    print('upper: ' + re.sub(r'[^A-Z]+', '', s))

inp = "Hello Siam,'How are You Today?'"
up_low(inp)
```

This prints:

```
lower: elloiamowareouoday
upper: HSHYT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also:

```
count_upper=[]  #it contains all the upper case letter
count_lower=[]  #it contains all the lower case letter
symbol=[]       #it contains all the symbols like space, comma etc

def up_low(phrase):
    for i in phrase:
        if i.isupper():
            global count_upper
            count_upper.append(i)
        elif i.islower():
            global count_lower
            count_lower.append(i)
        else:
            global symbol
            symbol.append(i)

up_low("Hello Siam,'How are You Today?'")

print(count_upper)
print(count_lower)
print(symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by **List Comprehension** after fixing `issupper()` to `isupper()` because **str** does not support `issupper()`.

**Code Syntax**

```
def up_low(s):
    v = [letter for letter in s if letter.islower()]
    v1 = [letter for letter in s if letter.isupper()]
    return f"The applited string has {len(v)} lowerCase character(s) and {len(v1)} highCase character (s)"
  

print(up_low("Hello Siam,'How are You Today?'"))
```

**Output**

```
The applited string has 18 lowerCase character(s) and 5 highCase character (s)

[Program finished]
```